# Getting the width for Chrome dev tools device emulation

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Basically I am writing a web application (using Bootstrap so it's responsive) that will accessed using tiny hand held scanners specifically this one:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/spec-sheets/mobile-computers/handheld/tc25.html

I need to make sure that the display works for both desktops and the handhelds so knowing this is important.

On there it has the display spec as "4.3 in. color WVGA (800x480); LED backlight; Corning Gorilla Glass"

Now when using chrome tools (emulated devices) I need to put the width and height in (I'm doing this to make sure the CSS is automatically adjusting correctly). Now what I need to know is the width and height.

I thought the first number (800) was suppose to be the width and the second number should be the height (800) but that can't be correct, unless they have put the spec back to front on their website?

I suspect that it should be in chrome tools 480 X 800 as that looks far more realistic. Would someone correct me here or point out if I'm missing something obvious?

Here is a picture of both devices  configuration in Chrome:

[image]

And here is the other dimension (which is believe to be the wrong one!)

[image]

When I try to research this question or find out myself I keep being told the first dimension is the width which just doesn't look right.

And this is the picture is the device itself:

[image]

Comment: When held vertically 480x800 is obviously the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first number represents the horizontally and the second one is for the vertically.
you can find out by dragging the responsive window and see which number changes.